# Plotting question in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

Is it possible to use the surf function to plot markers, e.g. surf(x,y,z,'some marker')?

Answer (score 4):

No. You can use [PLOT3](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/plot3.html) or [SCATTER3](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/scatter3.html) for that, though.

If you want both a surface and markers, plot the surface with surf, call [HOLD ON](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/hold.html), then plot the markers.